# Confused when creating new ASP.NET application template?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

Am sorry about odd title but i coludn't explain well what am i confused about in a few words.

When creating new ASP.NET application (Visual Studio 2015, framework), on the window where you get to choose which template you want.

[image: Selecting template]

I got confued about that number 4, what does it stands for?

MVC version -> In packages.config it says version is 5.2.3 ??

Comment: I'm going to guess that it represents ASP.NET 4 (4.6.1 in your case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4 as a superscript indicates the target framework of template(i.e. 4.5.2 in attached image for MVC) and by default it selects the latest version of target framework.

[image]

Target framework can be changed from solution properties window-->application(refer screen shot below).You can also take reference from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx)

[image]

Comment: So numbers 4.5.2 and in my case 4.6.1 stands for .NET framework that's targeted?

Answer (score 1):

4 stands for target framework, not for version.

there is difference between target framework and version.

Comment: 4 is for version of target framework. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx